# MVC view with Jqgrid

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, jqgrid

I'm using the Jqgrid in my C# MVC app. Everything works.  However, when the application runs, the view displays raw HTML (div tags, etc) then the screen is redrawn with the Jqgrid.  Is there a way to hide these div tags before the grid is fully drawn?  Thanks.

Comment: Can you put a screenshot in imageshack or something to show us what you mean?

Comment: I can't take a screenshot because it shows the div tag and the text boxes for a fraction of a second then the grids are displayed.  Maybe I'll try to take it with my phone on Monday.

Comment: It looks as if the HTML tags are displayed while JavaScript code is still executing.

Comment: @user2036588: Sorry, but I personally have no idea what you mean under "the view displays raw HTML (div tags, etc)". Could you reformulate the text, include screenshorts, include code fragments or in any other way explain more clrear what is the problem which you have?

Comment: Please, stop referring to "ASP.NET MVC" simply as "MVC". One is a framework, while other is a language-independent design pattern. It's like calling IE - "the internet"

Answer (score 0):

Say your grid is encapsulate in a Div with id of myGrid.

What you can do is in document ready event hide this div using $(‘# myGrid’).hide() and hookup into **gridComplete** event of jqGrid and re-display the #myGrid.

To be frank I have not done this as I have never encountered the scenario you described, but based on what described, it should work.. Let us know how it went..

Cheers

Comment: This was what I did to fix the problem.  I set the style to be <div id="myDiv" style="display: none">.  Then in the $(document).ready(), I just call $("#myDiv).show().  Thanks for all the suggestions.